# grunt SVG to webfont

Tags: html, css, svg, gruntjs, webfonts

I'm trying to generate webfont from SVGs using [grunt-webfont](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont).

The issue is that I need this task to be valid on windows and linux machines. In order to achieve this I need to use the node engines that [doesn’t work with some SVG files](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont#node).

I would like to know if there is a way to convert my SVGs to a proper SVG format that will be supported by this grunt plugin or alternatively is there a better grunt plugin/s to achieve this

I would like to have a task that will be able to take my SVGs (created in illustrator) and output webfont files (.eot,.svg,.svg,...) and a css file (like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) export)

Thanks.

Comment: do you have more specific information about what's wrong with your SVG files that prevents them from working?

Comment: Because I don't actually know what is wrong. the grunt-webfont API doesn't specify what is a good or bad format. All i know is that the SVGs were created in illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your artboard is too small. I recommend checking that you have a 512pt x 512pt artboard for each icon. I stumbled upon this gem  (https://www.fourdigits.nl/blog/using-a-webfont-to-display-icons) when the grunt-webfont documentation left me alone in the forest.

Answer (score 0):

All the docs says is that it *might* not work with *some* SVG files. You really should try to convert your files first and then ask what to do with the files that don’t work well.